# How do I replace tag's parentheses and text inside in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have an html expression that writes this way:

```
<li class="price-current"></span>
$
<strong>269</strong>
<sup>.49</sup>
&nbsp;
<a href="https://www.newegg.com/msi-geforce-gtx-1660-ti-gtx-
1660-ti-ventus-xs-6g-oc/p/N82E16814137392?Item
=N82E16814137392&amp;Description=graphic+cards&amp;buyingoptions=
New" class="price-current-num">(13 Offers)</a>
```

I'm using this line of code to extract the price from it which is also part of a bigger loop to go through all the tags that fit the requirement. Other tags have different price and Offers but in the same format.

```
Price = bulk.findAll("li", {"class": "price-current"})[0].text.strip().replace("$", "").replace("Offers", "")
```

The result I'm printing is 269.49 (13). I need to get rid of (13) and I don't know the syntax for it in the code. Thank you.

```
for bulk in bulks:
choose_tag = bulk.div.select("a")
Brand = choose_tag_sp[].img["title"].title()
Product = bulk.div.select("a")[2].text
shipping = bulk.findAll("li", {"class": "price-ship"})[0].text.strip().replace("$", "").replace(" Shipping", "")
price = ????

It's working fine with the code from MendelG
price = bulk.findAll("li", {"class": "price-current"})[0].find('strong')



print("Brand: " + Brand + "\n")
print("Product: " + Product + "\n")
print("shipping: " + shipping + "\n")
print(price..????

From MendelG
print(price.text + price.find_next('sup').text)
```

I would like to implement the other methods also because I'm learning right now how to do it and it doesn't hurt to know more than one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to find the position of the " (" in the string then strip the characters;

```
Price = "269.49 (13)";
pos = Price.find(" (",0,len(Price))
Price = Price[0:pos]
print(Price)
```

To fit your problem;

```
Price = bulk.findAll("li", {"class": "price-current"})[0].text.strip().replace("$", "").replace("Offers", "")
pos = Price.find(" (",0,len(Price))
if pos > 0:
    Price = Price[0:pos]
print(Price)
```

This will look at each Price value, if it contains a " (" then it will strip it off the end.

**Edit**
Had a mistake, price in lower case..

```
Price = bulk.findAll("li", {"class": "price-current"})[0].text.strip().replace("$", "").replace("Offers", "")
pos = Price.find(" (",0,len(Price))
if pos > 0:
    Price = Price[0:pos]
print(Price)
```

Comment: This is how is printed in the console: 269.49 (13) - ; 159.99 (2) - ; and so on. How do we change that? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

how about using regex:

```
import re
Price = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', Price)
```

That should remove everything between parentheses (including the parentheses themselves) in the price

Comment: I've been trying but I need to fit it in my loop. I updated my question please take a look.

Comment: put the regex line in your loop under the ```bulk.findAll()``` line

Comment: I just did and it prints only one product. Is it the mistake in the print line for it? print("Price:" + Price + "\n")

Comment: If it only prints one that seems like your code isn't inside the for loop.  Is it all indented underneath ```for bulk in bulks:``` ?

Comment: yes it's right under the Price = ...... and everything under for bulk in bulks loop. Is the print line code ok?

Comment: The print line looks fine.  If it's still printing only once something is either wrong with your loop or ```bulk``` only has one element

Comment: It's working. Only a little dash after the price that I'm not sure where it's coming from. It's printed 189.99 -, 269.49 - , and so on. I haven't change anything in your code.

Answer (score 1):

for this case I can suggest two options:

```
.replace('(13 Offers)', '')
```

the other option could be used for other cases too

```
price = Price.split(' ')
Price = price[0]  # or some other number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for a `<strong>` tag, and than use `find_next()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt  = """<li class="price-current"></span>
$
<strong>269</strong>
<sup>.49</sup>
&nbsp;
<a href="https://www.newegg.com/msi-geforce-gtx-1660-ti-gtx-
1660-ti-ventus-xs-6g-oc/p/N82E16814137392?Item
=N82E16814137392&amp;Description=graphic+cards&amp;buyingoptions=
New" class="price-current-num">(13 Offers)</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")

tags = soup.find("li", {"class": "price-current"}).find('strong')
print(tags.text + tags.find_next('sup').text)
```

Output:

```
269.49
```

Comment: Here is the thing. I have this loop and I need to fit the price expression in the loop:

Comment: I updated my question, please take another look. Thank you